# Org Mode: exporting agenda with inherited tags

Tags: emacs, org-mode

The [manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-commands.html) says:

> C-x C-w (org-agenda-write)
>
> Write the agenda view to a file. [...] only the body of original
>   headlines are exported, **not** subtrees or **inherited tags**.

How to export inherited tags anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution (answering own question):

```
(require 'org-mobile)
(setq org-mobile-creating-agendas t) ; to use (org-mobile-write-agenda-for-mobile)
(setq org-mobile-force-id-on-agenda-items nil) ; don't make all agenda items carry an ID
```

and then

C-x C-w (org-agenda-write)